# mod_wsgi and static pages (no django)

Tags: apache, mod-wsgi

On page: http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/FileWrapperExtension , Graham Dumpleton recommends the following:

> "Do note however that for the best performance, static files should
>   always be served by a web server. In the case of mod_wsgi this means
>   by Apache itself rather than mod_wsgi or the WSGI application."

I'd like to pre-build a large number of static pages, then have a python program (running under apache/mod_wsgi 3.3/python3.1, daemon mode, no django involved) decide which of them to serve to each user. I'd like the python program to decide, for example, that this guy needs "12345.html" and have it tell Apache, "please serve static file '12345.html' to this guy", rather than having to use python to open the file, read the contents, turn it into a python string, and return it to mod_wsgi as "[output]".

Is this possible? If so, how?

If not, what's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are numerous ways one could do it.

1. X-Sendfile implemented by mod_xsendfile and Apache.
2. Location/mod_rewrite tricks using mod_wsgi daemon mode.
3. X-Accel-Redirect if also using nginx as front end to Apache.

Read up on (1) and (3) as more widely used options.

---

Update with instructions for (2).

Have the WSGI application return a 200 response with empty body and 'Location' response header with URL path to local resource hosted on same Apache server and mod_wsgi when daemon mode is being used will trigger an internal redirect to that URL.

Thus if your Apache has:

```
Alias /generated-files/ /some/path/
<Directory /some/path>
Order allow, deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

then generate your file as /some/path/foo.txt in file system and then have the 'Location' response header have value '/generated-files/foo.txt' and it will be served up.

Note that anything under '/generated-files' is publicly accessible. If you didn't want this and wanted it to be private and so only returnable via the specific request which generated the 'Location' response header, you need to add mod_rewrite magic that blocks access to that URL except for an internally generated sub request. That from memory needs to be something like:

```
RewriteCond %{IS_SUBREQ} false
RewriteRule ^/generated-files/ - [F]
```

Comment: Regarding 1: I don't have access to mod_xsendfile on this shared server, but even if I did, it seems that this is implementing a download server of large, binary files, not for returning a Web page.

Comment: [sorry, I hit enter and it submitted it] Regarding 1: I don't have access to mod_xsendfile on this shared server, but even if I did, it seems that this is implementing a download server of large, binary files, not for returning a Web page. For 3: I'm just using your recommendation of basic apache+mod_wsgi in daemon mode being what most people need. So, #2 would seem to be the answer, but I'm not sure I understand the instructions: "tricks". Would these tricks, if I knew what they were, be faster than just reading the whole file in, making it one long string, and returning it as [output]?

Comment: You can still do (1). There is no restriction on using it for pre-generated web page content. As for (2), I will update answer after I get details together for you.

Comment: Thanks, Graham. If this is significantly faster than reading a whole file into a string then "return [output]"ing it, it would support a form of "secondary caching" of pre-generated responses.